# Add checkboxes next to google visualization barchart?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Is it possible to add checkboxes next to a google visualization barchart that has its own events? I do not want the checkboxes to hide/show any data, but to be attached some custom event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the checkboxes to your HTML and hook whatever events you want into them, but there is no way to add them to the chart itself.

Comment: My concern is alignment such that the checkbox is located right next to the words in the y axis. Is there some way to do that?

Comment: There is no reliable way to make sure they line up with the legend in the chart.  If that is your requirement, I would recommend turning off the chart's legend (set the legend.position option to "none"), and replacing it with a custom legend in HTML.